# Shouldn't the iterator types of Boost's small_vector satisfy the std::contiguous_iterator concept?

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, boost-container

It is possible to construct a `std::span` from a `std::vector` (as the prototype for a contiguous container), both via the range constructor and an explicit pair of iterators:

```
#include <span>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> owning;
std::span<int> view1{owning.begin(), owning.end()}; // works
std::span<int> view2{owning}; // works
```

But when doing the same with a `small_vector` from Boost's container library, which should be contiguous, too, I am running into issues ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8WdMGj69v)):

```
#include <span>
#include <boost/container/small_vector.hpp>

boost::container::small_vector<int, 10> owning;
std::span<int> view1{owning.begin(), owning.end()}; // Error
std::span<int> view2{owning}; // Error (works with clang + libc++ though)
```

The problem seems to be that the iterators of `boost::small_vector` don't satisfy the `std::contiguous_iterator` concept, i.e. this fails with both `gcc` and `clang`, `libc++` and `libstdcxx` ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oq8narEz8)):

```
static_assert(
    std::contiguous_iterator<boost::container::small_vector<int, 10>::iterator>);
```

The storage of `small_vector` might be in-place or on the heap, but always contiguous. So what's the issue here?

Comment: quick search shows this has been just recently fixed in [github repository](https://github.com/boostorg/container/issues/150)

Comment: Oh awesome! I had a search on the repo, but ony PRs, not issues... my bad, thanks! If you turn your comment into an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::contiguous_iterator` has [specific requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/contiguous_iterator) in C++20 which were not part of any pre-C++20 interface. Since those interfaces did not exist pre-C++20 (particularly the `contiguous_iterator_tag`), they couldn't be used by `small_vector<T>::iterator`.

Of course one can add such an interface, conditioned on the existence of C++20 features. But code written before the C++20 came about simply won't be able to be a `contiguous_iterator` without work to update it. While there was a C++17 "ContiguousIterator" requirement, it had no tag or other way to *detect* whether an iterator was contiguous. C++20 added such a tag (and other stuff) when it added a proper concept.